# Статичная кнопка

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть пример сдвигающегося дива. Как сделать чтобы зеленая кнопка всегда была на одном месте (статичная)
http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/383/
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так в чем сложность? В вашем примере, вы эту кнопку смещаете вместе с боковой панелью. Не трогайте её и [она останется на одном месте](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/XNnHC/403/).

Comment: Спасибо, делал ночью сидел и тупил :)